# How do I add data into combo box using vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to add unique data (From MainMenuData worksheet in same workbook) into ActiveX combo box placed on sheet1. Changed ComboBox Name from Properties to `ZoneDropDown`. Wrote following code on workbook open event.

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Dim Zn()

Dim R As Integer

For R = 1 To 248

    ZoneDropDown.AddItem Sheets("MainMenuData").Cells(R, 7)

Next

End Sub
```

It gives following error for ZoneDropDown

> Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
>    Compile error:
>
> Variable not defined

But if I place button on same worksheet (i.e. sheet1) above code execute successfully and data added into combo box.

Comment: You have not defined `Dim Zn()` as anything (integer, string, etc.). What is it for? If you remark it out, does the code work?

Comment: Insted of 
ZoneDropDown.AddItem Sheets("MainMenuData").Cells(R, 7)


I change to 
Sheets("Sheet1").ZoneDropDown.AddItem Sheets("MainMenuData").Cells(R, 7)

& it works